# Date time formatting error, when submitted via Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datepicker

I am having a wired issue and I can't seem to figure it out.

I am using `DatePicker` to create my `DateTime` values in Input field. Now when I use `DatePicker` submission works fine.

Issue comes up when I edit the data, so I would open my form X and input filed will populate date such as `Monday, Jan 10, 2018 10:30am`

If I click save changes at this time, `back-end` receives `string` such as

> %25E2%2580%258EJan%25E2%2580%258E%2520%25E2%2580%258E15%25E2%2580%258E%252C%2520%25E2%2580%258E2018%25E2%2580%258E%2520%25E2%2580%258E10%25E2%2580%258E%253A%25E2%2580%258E24%25E2%2580%258E%2520%25E2%2580%258EAM

and so on, I think you get the picture. I even tried creating a `new Date(string)` before `Ajax` submit but same thing happens.

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("eventDateTime", document.getElementById("eventDateTime").value);
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        url: "",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (output) {
        }
    });
```

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: No code provided in the question.

Comment: Looks like it is sending String and not Date. We would need to see your AJAX code to understand better.

Comment: Code added to the OP

Comment: It looks like your string is getting doubly encoded, if you run `decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(dateString))` you get `"‎Jan‎ ‎15‎, ‎2018‎ ‎10‎:‎24‎ ‎AM"`

Answer (score 0):

Try encodeURIComponent.

Example:

var encoded = encodeURIComponent(str);

Comment: That didn't work I got some issue, thank you for trying!